# Can not start the Pentaho with tomcat service

Tags: tomcat7, pentaho

I want run a Pentaho with tomcat but when i start the (startPentaho.bat), i receive at finally the line who indicate in the figure.
[image]

I hope receive any indication to resolve my problem.

Comment: Guess you are on windows. Where did get the code from : pentaho web site? Source Forge? Compiled from github? Standard install or customized?

Comment: You indicate a tomcat7 while the log indicates a tomcat 8.

Comment: hi, yes now i use a tomcat 8 but i tried with tomcat 7. i'm on windows 7 and the pentaho-server 7. how can i attached a figure to this comment please ?